# node.bcrypt.js, error: “undefined No callback function was given”

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, bcrypt

So I'm currently taking Mosh Hamdani's Mastering React Course and the back-end development has given me a number of problems. The most recent one being error: “undefined No callback function was given”. I'm trying to register a new user using bcrypt.

To fix the problem I've tried using:

```
const salt = bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(_err, salt) {
bcrypt.hash(user.name, salt, function(_err, hash) {
    // Store hash in your password DB.
});
});
```

from https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt and even that didn't work.

If anyone could please help me it would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my user.js file:

```
  const auth = require("../middleware/auth");
  const bcrypt = require("bcrypt-nodejs");
  const _ = require("lodash");
  const { User, validate } = require("../models/user");
  const express = require("express");
  const router = express.Router();

  router.get("/me", auth, async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id).select("-password");
  res.send(user);
  });

 router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
 const { error } = validate(req.body);
 if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

 let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
 if (user) return res.status(400).send("User already registered.");

 user = new User(_.pick(req.body, ["name", "email", "password"]));
 const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
 user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
 await user.save();

 const token = user.generateAuthToken();
 res
.header("x-auth-token", token)
.send(_.pick(user, ["_id", "name", "email"]));
 });

 module.exports = router;
```

Here's a warning I was given in my terminal:

(node:7776) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
(node:7776) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the
new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
info: Listening on port 3900...
(node:7776) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace of the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Okay what I failed to realize earlier ago is that bcrypt-nodejs is no longer active https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs. Instead use bcryptjs  https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt.

Also I upgraded my code to:

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (_err, salt) {
bcrypt.hash(user.name, salt, function (_err, hash) {
 // Store hash in your password DB.
 user.password = hash;
});
});
```